# How to enable SMTP port 25 in Google Cloud Redhat 7 instance?

Tags: smtp, google-cloud-platform, firewall

I am using `webmail` to configure the mail service. the webmail to any external mail providers(gmail,yahoo) is not working. the serviceis working fine within webmail to webmail accounts. from research i found that google cloud is not allowing `SMTP` to connect on PORT 25.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Google documentation on sending email](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) describes in detail all the options available for sending out email from a Google Cloud instance.

To summarize the document, Google does not allow access to port 25 from a Google instance for security reasons. All other ports can be used to send out email. If you want to send out email from port 25, then your only option is to use a VPN.

You can also use third party email providers like Mailgun and SendGrid.

Another option is to send email through a gmail or google apps account from port 465 or port 587.

As I understand you are not able to use webmail for connecting to third party email providers like Yahoo and Google. This should not be a problem now since all email providers use the ports 465 or 587 for sending out email. These ports are allowed by Google

Comment: can i enable port 456 for webmail?

Comment: No I think only port 587 can be used, but you can check if port 465 is available. Only Google's mail server can be accessed

Comment: You do not have to use a third party service.  You just can't send out or port 25 because it is not secure.

Comment: You can use any port for sending out email except for port 25, which is closed due to security reasons. You can also use third party email providers such as MailGun. If you need to connect to a mail server on port 25, then you can use VPN

Comment: GCloud documentation tells you how to do it.  You can use a relay.  They also tell you WHY.  Recommending people to use a 3rd party service is not REQUIRED is my point which is the way you made it sound.  That is the reason for the down vote.  If you are mad about it just update your answer. "Then you have to use a third party service" <-- see..

Answer (score 1):

Google Compute Engine has outgoing SMTP ports blocked by design. Please vote here to get Google's SMTP behavior changed:
https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/10079937-send-and-receive-email-using-tcp-smtp-imap-ports

Until they open the SMTP ports, there will be *no* good way to send email from their cloud servers. Sendgrid and the others are too expensive or lack many features that are needed.

Apparently, Port 25 is a must too, but voting to have it opened is in a different location: https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/12422808-please-unblock-port-25-allow-outbound-mail-connec

Comment: "How do I enable port 25 in Google Cloud?" He asked. Getting Google to stop blocking the correct ports is the only exact solution to this.

Comment: This is no longer valid.

Comment: We're still waiting on the port 25.

Comment: Sure, but we have 2525 and 587 now.  So we do have "good ways" to send SMTP mail.  I just stumbled on this and everyones answers were outdated.  I understand GCloud is annoying with this feature, but I get it.  I just was letting people know so that the random searcher would know this is the case.

Comment: Just so a random searcher doesn't get confused: Most servers do not accept server-to-server email from any port other than 25. All these other ports discussed here are only for client-to-server communication, not server-to-server communication that is needed to actually get your email across the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use port 2525 to send email from google cloud. Almost all major email service providers support port 2525. But all other smtp ports are blocked for outbound mail.

Comment: This sent me down a bit of a rabbit hole - how do you configure the _outgoing_ SMTP port for sending mail (not the relay port).  I searched the exim and postfix docs and still can't figure this out.  Doesn't seem to be `daemon_smtp_ports` (exim) or `smtp inet n – n – – smtpd` (postfix).

Comment: You can't actually configure ports. The port is decided by the smtp server. Most smtp service providers allow multiple ports such as 25, 2525 and 587. you have to pick one of those. And since ports such as 25, 587 are blocked from cloud providers firewall which you don't have access to, you can most of the time use 2525.

Comment: Sure, I understand you can't configure the _incoming_ port on the mail server receiving the mail, but how do you send mail to that server on 2525?  It seems to always go to port 25, which GCP blocks as an _outgoing_ port.

Comment: You can't send email from your Google server directly to other email servers without an external SMTP service of some kind. Unlike all other hosting companies that allow you to send email out directly from your own server with no extra services needed. This is why they say you must use Gmail, Sendgrid, Mailgun, or some other SMTP service. You can't just change the ports and get email to go out because most destination servers only communicate via port 25 between servers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the "incoming port 25" is blocked....only "outgoing". The relay service is to stop spam going out from google cloud thhs ruining ip address reputation on their network.
Public ip addresses are not free...even for google. They must be purchased, so ip address reputation and avoiding blacklisting is very important for large service providers. 
This has been done because spammers setup scripts to quickly spin up new instances, send email spam until they are blacklisted, move to a new ip address and than get blacklisted again, move to a new ip address keep on spamming...over and over again leaving a trail of blacklisted public ip addresses in their wake.